# why is a JSON file not getting read by my app?

Tags: android, json

I am new to Stackoverflow and this is my first question.
I am developing an application where I am reading data from a json file from assets folder and storing the values in array list.
here is my code

```
   try {
        JSONObject object=new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        String objec=object.getString("root");
        JSONObject object1=new JSONObject(objec);
        JSONArray array=object1.getJSONArray("child");
        for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject=array.getJSONObject(i);
            list.add(String.valueOf(jsonObject));

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootview;
}
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("data.json");

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        is.read(buffer);

        is.close();

        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;

}
```

And this is my json data structure

```
 "root" : {
"child" : [ "data1","data2","data3",.......]},
```

I want the data1,data2 values inside a list

Comment: please check my ans.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 try {
        JSONObject object=new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        String objec=object.getString("root");
        JSONObject object1=new JSONObject(objec);
        JSONArray array=object1.getJSONArray("child");
        for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
        {
            list.add(array.getString(i));

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
    JSONObject object=new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
    String objec=object.getString("root");
    JSONObject object1=new JSONObject(objec);
    JSONArray array=object1.getJSONArray("child");
    for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
    {
        JSONObject jsonObject=array.getJSONObject(i);
        list.add(jsonObject.getString(i));

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```